# authentication class wont let me save in the user model

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am trying to save ( $user->save();) the access token to my user table for later use. 
but for some reason its not saving to my table.

here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace api\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\filters\auth\CompositeAuth;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;
use yii\filters\auth\QueryParamAuth;
use common\models\Authentication;

class AuthenticationController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'common\models\Authentication';

    public function actionGrantAuthentication()
    {

        $access_token = null;

        $message = array();

        if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {

            if (!Yii::$app->user->identity || !Yii::$app->user->identity || Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {

                $username = isset(Yii::$app->request->post()['username']) && Yii::$app->request->post()['username'] ? Yii::$app->request->post()['username'] : null;

                $password = isset(Yii::$app->request->post()['password']) && Yii::$app->request->post()['password'] ? Yii::$app->request->post()['password'] : null;

                if ($username && $password) {
                    $user = Authentication::findOne(['username' => $username, 'password_hash' => $password]);

                    if ($user) {
                        //log this user in if the identity is verified
                        Yii::$app->user->login($user);

                        $user->access_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();

                        $user->auth_key = "djfskdjh";

                        $user->save();

                        $message[] = $user;

                    } else {
                        //add error message
                        $message[] = "Wrong login credentials";
                    }

                } else {
                    $message[] = "Must provide username and password";
                }
            } else {
                $message[] = "you are already logged in";
            }
        }


        return $message;

    }

}
```

here is my authentication model

```
<?php
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

/**
 * User model
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $password_hash
 * @property string $password_reset_token
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $auth_key
 * @property integer $status
 * @property integer $created_at
 * @property integer $updated_at
 * @property string $password write-only password
 */
class Authentication extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        //throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
        return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['username' => $username]);
    }


    /**
     * Finds user by password reset token
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token)
    {
        if (!static::isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)) {
            return null;
        }

        return static::findOne([
            'password_reset_token' => $token,
            'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds out if password reset token is valid
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)
    {
        if (empty($token)) {
            return false;
        }

        $timestamp = (int) substr($token, strrpos($token, '_') + 1);
        $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
        return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }

    /**
     * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }

    /**
     * Generates "remember me" authentication key
     */
    public function generateAuthKey()
    {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }

    /**
     * Generates new password reset token
     */
    public function generatePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
    }

    /**
     * Removes password reset token
     */
    public function removePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = null;
    }
}
```

here is my table

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tipically when a model is not saved in DB this is related to validation problem ..

You can try using for debugging

```
     $user->save(false);  //this disable the validation rules for user
```

Then is the user i saved in db you should looking for the validation rule that fail

you can look at this guide for some suggetion for getting the validation errors

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html

```
if ($user->validate()) {
     // all inputs are valid
     $user->save()
} else {
    // validation failed: $errors is an array containing error messages
     $errors = $model->errors;
     var_dump($errors);
}
```

Comment: I tried that but its giving me "type": "yii\\base\\UnknownPropertyException"

Comment: you have a column type that is not present in table (or in model/interface )? check please ..

Comment: Try using the code provided and let me know the var_dump(errors) result

Comment: Thank you very much  .. could you  tell what the real problem ?

Comment: its the updated_at field that was missing in the table. I added that and it seemed to start saving just fine. Without passing false through. I am not sure why it was validating that filed since I dont think I added it.